# Добавление строк в RecycleView

Tags: android, android-fragment

Пытаюсь изучить RecycleView, но ни как не могу понять как из MainActivty можно добавить строку в конец RecycleView в уже существующий и отображённый RecycleView? Или это нужно делать в другом месте?

```
public class MainActivity extends SampleActivityBase {

public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

// Whether the Log Fragment is currently shown
private boolean mLogShown;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        RecyclerViewFragment fragment = new RecyclerViewFragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem logToggle = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_toggle_log);
    logToggle.setVisible(findViewById(R.id.sample_output) instanceof ViewAnimator);
    logToggle.setTitle(mLogShown ? R.string.sample_hide_log : R.string.sample_show_log);

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_toggle_log:
            mLogShown = !mLogShown;
            ViewAnimator output = (ViewAnimator) findViewById(R.id.sample_output);
            if (mLogShown) {
                output.setDisplayedChild(1);
            } else {
                output.setDisplayedChild(0);
            }
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/** Create a chain of targets that will receive log data */
@Override
public void initializeLogging() {
    // Wraps Android's native log framework.
    LogWrapper logWrapper = new LogWrapper();
    // Using Log, front-end to the logging chain, emulates android.util.log method signatures.
    Log.setLogNode(logWrapper);

    // Filter strips out everything except the message text.
    MessageOnlyLogFilter msgFilter = new MessageOnlyLogFilter();
    logWrapper.setNext(msgFilter);

    // On screen logging via a fragment with a TextView.
    LogFragment logFragment = (LogFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.log_fragment);
    msgFilter.setNext(logFragment.getLogView());

    Log.i(TAG, "Ready");
}
}
```

Адаптер

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private static final String TAG = "CustomAdapter";

private String[] mDataSet;

// BEGIN_INCLUDE(recyclerViewSampleViewHolder)
/**
 * Provide a reference to the type of views that you are using (custom ViewHolder)
 */
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final TextView textView;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        // Define click listener for the ViewHolder's View.
        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Element " + getAdapterPosition() + " clicked.");
            }
        });
        textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }

    public TextView getTextView() {
        return textView;
    }
}
// END_INCLUDE(recyclerViewSampleViewHolder)

/**
 * Initialize the dataset of the Adapter.
 *
 * @param dataSet String[] containing the data to populate views to be used by RecyclerView.
 */
public CustomAdapter(String[] dataSet) {
    mDataSet = dataSet;
}

// BEGIN_INCLUDE(recyclerViewOnCreateViewHolder)
// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    // Create a new view.
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.text_row_item, viewGroup, false);

    return new ViewHolder(v);
}
// END_INCLUDE(recyclerViewOnCreateViewHolder)

// BEGIN_INCLUDE(recyclerViewOnBindViewHolder)
// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Element " + position + " set.");

    // Get element from your dataset at this position and replace the contents of the view
    // with that element
    viewHolder.getTextView().setText(mDataSet[position]);
}
// END_INCLUDE(recyclerViewOnBindViewHolder)

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataSet.length;
}
}
```

Фрагмент

```
public class RecyclerViewFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewFragment";
private static final String KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER = "layoutManager";
private static final int SPAN_COUNT = 2;
private static final int DATASET_COUNT = 60;

private enum LayoutManagerType {
    GRID_LAYOUT_MANAGER,
    LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER
}

protected LayoutManagerType mCurrentLayoutManagerType;

protected RadioButton mLinearLayoutRadioButton;
protected RadioButton mGridLayoutRadioButton;

protected RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
protected CustomAdapter mAdapter;
protected RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
protected String[] mDataset;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Initialize dataset, this data would usually come from a local content provider or
    // remote server.
    initDataset();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_frag, container, false);
    rootView.setTag(TAG);

    // BEGIN_INCLUDE(initializeRecyclerView)
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    // LinearLayoutManager is used here, this will layout the elements in a similar fashion
    // to the way ListView would layout elements. The RecyclerView.LayoutManager defines how
    // elements are laid out.
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

    mCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER;

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore saved layout manager type.
        mCurrentLayoutManagerType = (LayoutManagerType) savedInstanceState
                .getSerializable(KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER);
    }
    setRecyclerViewLayoutManager(mCurrentLayoutManagerType);

    mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(mDataset);
    // Set CustomAdapter as the adapter for RecyclerView.
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    // END_INCLUDE(initializeRecyclerView)

    mLinearLayoutRadioButton = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_rb);
    mLinearLayoutRadioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setRecyclerViewLayoutManager(LayoutManagerType.LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER);
        }
    });

    mGridLayoutRadioButton = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_layout_rb);
    mGridLayoutRadioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setRecyclerViewLayoutManager(LayoutManagerType.GRID_LAYOUT_MANAGER);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

/**
 * Set RecyclerView's LayoutManager to the one given.
 *
 * @param layoutManagerType Type of layout manager to switch to.
 */
public void setRecyclerViewLayoutManager(LayoutManagerType layoutManagerType) {
    int scrollPosition = 0;

    // If a layout manager has already been set, get current scroll position.
    if (mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager() != null) {
        scrollPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager())
                .findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
    }

    switch (layoutManagerType) {
        case GRID_LAYOUT_MANAGER:
            mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), SPAN_COUNT);
            mCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.GRID_LAYOUT_MANAGER;
            break;
        case LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER:
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            mCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER;
            break;
        default:
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            mCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER;
    }

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(scrollPosition);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save currently selected layout manager.
    savedInstanceState.putSerializable(KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER, mCurrentLayoutManagerType);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

/**
 * Generates Strings for RecyclerView's adapter. This data would usually come
 * from a local content provider or remote server.
 */
private void initDataset() {
    mDataset = new String[DATASET_COUNT];
    for (int i = 0; i < DATASET_COUNT; i++) {
        mDataset[i] = "This is element #" + i;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял - строка это просто элемент списка который вам нужно добавить в конец списка. Алгоритм действий таков:

1. Вы грузите в адаптер RecyclerView массив с некоторым количеством элементов
2. Добавляете в ваш старый массив новый элемент в конец
3. Перезагружаете адаптер

Теперь более подробно. У вас есть массив который вы передаете в конструктор адаптера:

```
String[] mDataset
...
mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(mDataset);
// Set CustomAdapter as the adapter for RecyclerView.
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

соответственно вам нужно в этот массив добавить элемент в самый конец. Честно говоря такой массив имеет некоторые ограничения, поэтому я бы вам советовал заменить его на ArrayList. Чтобы вы не думали что так прям просто добавлять элементы:

```
String[] array1 = new String[]{"one", "two"};
String[] array2 = new String[]{"three"};
String[] array = new String[array1.length + array2.length];
System.arraycopy(array1, 0, array, 0, array1.length);
System.arraycopy(array2, 0, array, array1.length, array2.length);
```

то есть у вас есть массив с определенным размером, и потом вам нужно будет создавать новый массив и все в этом духе. Это очень громоздко и не совсем правильно. Поэтому вернемся к ArrayList. Объявим его:

```
ArrayList<String> mDataset = new ArrayList<String>();
```

ваш метод добавления данных в массив:

```
private void initDataset() {
    for (int i = 0; i < DATASET_COUNT; i++) {
       mDataset.add(i, "This is element #" + i);
    }
}
```

[Вот если что есть туториал](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_add_index.htm#:%7E:text=The%20java.,add%20one%20to%20their%20indices) по работе с ArrayList. Так же нужно изменить конструктор адаптера:

```
private ArrayList<String> mDataset;
public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> dataSet) {
    mDataSet = dataSet;
}
```

ну и наконец добавление элемента в конец списка:

```
mDataset.add(mDataset.size(), "Last element");
```

и обновление списка:

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Если же вам нужно передавать данные из MainActivity, то советую использовать bundle чтобы передать данные в фрагмент и потом добавить в массив. [Вот пример работы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android)

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы данные из MainActivity передавались не сразу, а в процессе работы приложения. Можно ли передавать данные не во врея создания фрагмента а уже после?

Comment: тогда вам уже нужно добавлять данные из фрагмента а не из активности